# java multithreading series task execution

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose four threads have to do tasks. Each thread has to do a single unit work. how to know which thread has finished its work to assign it next work.

actually, I have to use 4 threads and each thread has to copy one column of a 2d array into 1d array..

Edit : Without using Threadpool.
Many Thanks.

Comment: Have the threads pull the work from a shared (synchronized) work queue, and loop all the time, pulling the next item from the queue?

Comment: actually, I have to use 4 threads and each thread has to copy one column of a 2d array into 1d array.. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're submitting tasks to threads, the same effect can be accomplished using this:

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (4);

    for (int i=1; i<=TOTAL_TASKS; i++) {
        es.submit (new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                // Do work here!
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: could it be done without using Threadpool?
Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know you had that specific constraint. So, without using a ThreadPool one option is to do what JP Moresmau suggest -- using a work queue, and pull entries from it that allow your thread code to process the next work item. Wanted to clarify: The threads are destroyed once they finish execution, so you simply cannot let run() method finish to its end and expect to assign more work to a thread, since it has already died.

Comment: Expanding on what @JoseCifuentes said, you should use a blocking work queue to avoid Thread termination.